# Android - Best place to add views inside custom viewgroup/relativelayout when width is known

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I am currently optimising a complex view containing many nested views. therefor i have created a custom layout extending the relativelayout class.
Based on data set from outside the class i further build the view with childs.
The child building is done within the custom layout. I got it working and the performance gain is enourmous. But before i can create and add the childs i need to know the width of the view. 
There are several ways of getting the width of the view:

1 add global layout listener

```
public void init(){

 getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //width is known -> create child views
        }
    });
 }
```

This solution does not always fire an event. For example when the view is inside a fragment and restored from a backstack state. Also there seem to be a 100 to 500ms delay before this event is triggered.

2. in onMeasure

   ```
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
   setMeasuredDimension(w, h);

   post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //width is known -> create child views  
           MyCustomViewGroup.this.postInvalidate();
       }
   });

   }
   ```

The difficulty here is that adding views inside onmeasure will result into a call to onmeasure again. And endless loop is the result. Logic needed to prevent this. Could't figure out how.

3 add views in onLayout

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    //width is known -> create child views
}
```

Various unexpected layout problems. Views not respecting layoutparams and showing weird behaviour. Not really sure how to solve it.

4. hacky timer implementation

   ```
   private Handler ha = new Handler();
   private Runnable r;

   public void init() {
       if (w > 0) {
           //width is known ->create childs
           return;
       }
       r = new Runnable() {

           private long time = 0;

           @Override
           public void run() {
               Log.d(TAG, "run");
               if (w > 0) {
                   //width is known ->create childs
               } else {
                   init(); //width is not known -> check later
               }
           }
       };
       ha.postDelayed(r, 5);
   }
   ```

Ironically the last solution works best for me.
I know its a hell of a hack. 
is there is anyone out there knowing alternatives? or can give me tips.

Comment: `2`, but mainly `4`: you could use an AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: tried addViewInLayout?

Comment: But honestly i don't really know why do you need the parents size while adding the children,  its really strange...

Comment: i need to know the size because i want to layout the views manualy. i know that i can achieve the same with linearlayouts or relativelayouts. I just need to manualy layout every view so i can speed up the entire view.

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot so do it in onLayout method,  iterate over each child view and call layout(l, t, r, b)  on it